# jQuery each() breaking on null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object that I am looping over with each() to add table rows to a table.  I can't ensure the completeness of the data presented in the JSON arrays and I occasionally run into some NULLs.

For instance:

```
// A GOOD ARRAY 
{
id: "193",
location: {
city: "Atlanta",
state: "GA"
},
name: "John"
},
// NOW WE STUMBLE UPON A BAD ARRAY WITH A NULL
{
id: "194",
location: {
city: "Boise",
state: null
},
name: "Frank"
},
{...}
```

Now, when I am dealing with JSON objects that have no NULL values, the each() loops over with no problems.  As soon as I encounter a member with NULL anywhere in the array, the looping breaks.

This is how I am looping over this:

```
$.getJSON("/getstuff/jsonprovider.php", function (data) {

        var results = data.parentnode;

        var tableThing = $(".myTable tbody");
            var i = 0;

        $.each(results, function () {
                tableThing.append('<tr><td></td><td>' + results[i].id + '</td><td>' + results[i].name + '</td><td>' + results[i].location.city + ', ' + results[i].location.state + '</td></tr>');
        i++;
        });

        });
```

Should I be investigating something other than each() here, or should I be using a completely different method?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't your keys be in quotes?

Comment: It doesn't matter if they are not in quotes but it is considered as a good practice to keep them inside the quotes.

Comment: can you post your Javascript code aswell

Comment: null values seem to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XHQ3U/1/. You do need to wrap your keys in quotes as @arxanas suggested.

Comment: Your problem is probably in your each function. Are you sure you don't try to apply a function to the state or read a parameter of the state ?

Comment: Is the ajax failing with `parseerror`, or is the .each failing when it reaches a key that has a value of null.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/emphaticsunshine/XHQ3U/3/ . Its not a requirement to have quotes but it is suggested to have quotes around index

Comment: Sorry, I ripped the JSON from a beautifier that takes the quotes off.  The JSON is not malformed and the keys are quoted.  Posting jQuery in a sec. THanks

Comment: @emphaticsunshine It is required to have quotes if it is a JSON string. Without quotes, you won't even reach the `.each`. Your fiddle deals with an object, not a JSON string. I'm sure what he posted is just a sample and not the actual JSON which probably has the quotes, otherwise, as i said, he wouldn't have even reached the `.each`. The lack of quotes isn't the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data may have nulls, you need to make sure that the data exists before you attempt to use it. It is also more efficient to only use `.append` once. Below i'm using a default empty object and $.extend deep copy to ensure that the object we are pulling data from always has all data values defined, even if the value isn't in the json. I'm still not sure how null's will be handled at this point.

```
var emptyObj = {
    id: "",
    name: "",
    location: {
        city: "",
        state: ""
    }
},htmlToAppend = "";

$.each(results, function (i,obj) {
    var newObj = $.extend(true,{},emptyObj,obj);
    htmlToAppend += '<tr><td></td><td>' + newObj.id + '</td><td>' + newObj.name + '</td><td>' + newObj.location.city + ', ' + newObj.location.state + '</td></tr>';
});
tableThing.append(htmlToAppend);
```

Comment: I am trying to factor this for my needs, but am missing something here... only retuning the "empty" object http://jsfiddle.net/HCbsM/4/

Comment: in your fiddle your dealing with an object, not an array. try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/HCbsM/6/

Comment: Kevin... ALL KILLER... NO FILLER. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do a `$.each` is like this:

```
var myObj = {...};
$.each(myObj, function(k, v){ 
    //..
});
```

You need two parameters above:

- k holds the index or the key
- v holds the value at that index or key

If you were going to use a counter variable like `i` you might as well use JavaScripts `for in` loop:

```
for(var i in myObj){
   //..
}
```